# How could I read a text file and implement a tree based on those values?

Tags: go, data-structures

I'm trying to implement DFS (Depth First Search) algorithm using Go, but my actual code need to add node by node to build the tree, manually. I want to read a text file, with this data (example):

```
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 83 47 65
```

And build the tree with these values. The root value will be 75,left 95, right 64 and so on.

This is my complete code:

```golang
// Package main implements the DFS algorithm
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

// Node handle all the tree data
type Node struct {
    Data  interface {}
    Left  *Node
    Right *Node
}

// NewNode creates a new node to the tree
func NewNode(data interface{}) *Node {
    node := new(Node)

    node.Data = data
    node.Left = nil
    node.Right = nil

    return node
}

// FillNodes create all the nodes based on each value on file
func FillNodes(lines *[][]string) {
    nodes := *lines

    rootInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(nodes[0][0])
    root := NewNode(rootInt)

    // add the values here

    wg.Add(1)
    go root.DFS()

    wg.Wait()

}

// ProcessNode checks and print the actual node
func (n *Node) ProcessNode() {
    defer wg.Done()

    var hello []int

    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        hello = append(hello, i)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Node    %v\n", n.Data)
}

// DFS calls itself on each node
func (n *Node) DFS() {
    defer wg.Done()

    if n == nil {
        return
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go n.Left.DFS()

    wg.Add(1)
    go n.ProcessNode()

    wg.Add(1)
    go n.Right.DFS()
}

// CheckError handle erros check
func CheckError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// OpenFile handle reading data from a text file
func OpenFile() [][]string {
    var lines [][]string

    ftpr := flag.String("fpath", "pyramid2.txt", "./pyramid2.txt")
    flag.Parse()

    f, err := os.Open(*ftpr)
    CheckError(err)

    defer func() {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for s.Scan() {
        line := strings.Fields(s.Text())
        lines = append(lines, line)
    }

    err = s.Err()
    CheckError(err)


    return lines
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Main creates the tree and call DFS
func main() {
    nodes := OpenFile()

    FillNodes(&nodes)
}
```

What would be a possible solution to this? Also, How I could convert all those string to int on a easy way?

Comment: in the second layer 95 and 64 should have 4 child but in the third layer there is just three number, how we find out they are belong to each node?

Comment: 47 belongs to both nodes... In final version would be possible to read this file and determine the "route" of the greatest sum.

Comment: As a first step, I recommend you get rid of waitgroups and goroutines. Are you asking how to search in the tree, or how to build the tree?

Comment: Why? Ok, at first I need to build the tree and then search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method for the creation of the tree (didn't test it):

```
func FillLevel(parents []*Node, level []string) (children []*Node, err error){
    if len(parents) + 1 != len(level) {
        return nil, errors.New("params size not OK")
    }

    for i, p := range parents {
        leftVal, err := strconv.Atoi(level[i])
        rightVal, err := strconv.Atoi(level[i+1])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        p.Left = NewNode(leftVal)
        p.Right = NewNode(rightVal)
        children = append(children, p.Left)
        if i == len(parents) - 1 {
            children = append(children, p.Right)
        }
    }
    return children, nil
}

func FillNodes(lines *[][]string) (*Node, error){
    nodes := *lines

    rootInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(nodes[0][0])
    root := NewNode(rootInt)

    // add the values here
    parents := []*Node{root}
    for _, level := range nodes[1:] {
        parents, _ = FillLevel(parents, level)
    }
    return root, nil
}

func main() {
    nodes := OpenFile()
    r, _ := FillNodes(&nodes)
    wg.Add(1)
    r.DFS()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

If this is for production, my advice is to TDD it, and to handle all the errors correctly and decide what your software should do about each one of them. You can also write some benchmarks, and then optimize the algorithm using goroutines (if applicable)

The way you're doing right now, you're better off without goroutines:
Imagine you have a huge tree, with 1M nodes, the DFS func will recursively launch 1M goroutines, each one of them has a memory & CPU additional cost without doing much to justify it. You need a better way of splitting the work to do on far fewer goroutines, maybe 10000 nodes per each goroutine.

I would strongly advise you to write a version without goroutines, study it's complexity, write benchmarks to validate the expected complexity. Once you have that, start looking for a strategy to introduce goroutines, and validate that it's more efficient that what you already have.

Comment: Worked like a charm! No, it's kinda a challenge that I mada myself but I gave up... But someday I'll implement tests, I need to learn unit tests on Go too! Thank you for your help. Why the ProcessNode func only prints out only seven times? I miss something on this implementation?

Comment: And you could gave a tip on how I could achieve my goal? I need to get the greatest sum of the tree but I really getting stuck with this. Any starting point I would appreciate!

Comment: Well, now I'm getting an Invalid memory address error when I try o access the seventh node.

Comment: hi, I edited the FillLevel code, turns out I was adding some of the node more than one time, I think now is OK

Comment: Regarding the DFS func, in your code, you are not calling wg.Wait anywhere, you should wg.Wait for all your goroutines to complete, it prints only 7 times because that's all the routines could do before the main thread finished

Comment: I added the main func to the answer, with the call to wg.Wait

Comment: Ok! I got rid og goroutines for now! And now all the nodes are processed. Thank you!